# React-Redux Actions may not have an undefined "type" property

Tags: reactjs, redux

When I using `redux-api-middleware` on dispatching action, I got this error :

> × Error: Actions may not have an undefined "type" property. Have you
>   misspelled a constant?

I guess my applyMiddleware method is incorrect.

**my index.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk'
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import {apiMiddleware} from 'redux-api-middleware';

import Root from './containers/Root'
import rootReducer from './reducers'
import history from './constants/history'

const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(apiMiddleware, thunkMiddleware))

render(
    <Router history={history}>
        <Root store={store} />
    </Router>
   ,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

---

This package's readme applied middleware like below:

**official doc's configureStore.js**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { apiMiddleware } from 'redux-api-middleware';
import reducers from './reducers';

const reducer = combineReducers(reducers);
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(apiMiddleware)(createStore);

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
  return createStoreWithMiddleware(reducer, initialState);
}
```

**official doc's app.js**

```
const store = configureStore(initialState);
```

But I don't know how to apply this in my structure, am I wrong something?

Add...

This is my code block

** LoginPage.js**

```
const LoginPage = ({dispatch, auth}) => {

    let emailInput, passwordInput;

    if(auth.user){
        return <Redirect to="/dashboard" />
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h3>Login</h3>

            <form onSubmit={e => {
                e.preventDefault()
                if (!emailInput.value.trim() || !passwordInput.value.trim()) {
                    return
                }
                dispatch(processLogin({
                    email: emailInput.value.trim(),
                    password: passwordInput.value.trim(),

                }))
            }}>
                <input type="text" ref={node => emailInput = node} placeholder="example@email.com"/>
                <input type="password" ref={node => passwordInput = node} placeholder="password"/>
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        auth : state.auth
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(LoginPage)
```

**actions.js**

```
export const processLogin = (user) => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch({
            [RSAA]: {
                endpoint: "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/sign-in",
                method: "POST",
                body: JSON.stringify({email: user.email, password: user.password}),
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
                types: ['LOGIN', 'LOGIN_SUCCESS', 'LOGIN_FAILURE']
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems an issue in dispatching an action and not in store configuration

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Hi, I added my component and action file, I don't know what is wrong, can you see this with just few seconds..? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for helping me @Yury and @Khatri

The problem was a silly mistake,

I chagned

```
import RSAA from 'redux-api-middleware'
```

to

```
import { RSAA } from 'redux-api-middleware'
```

and it's working.

Thanks for helps...

Answer (score 1):

Your `processLogin` returns a thunk (ie. function not an object). You have to either add `redux-thunk` middleware **before** `apiMiddleware` to handle functions

```
const store = createStore(rootReducer, {}, applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware, apiMiddleware))
```

or make `processLogin` to return an object.

```
export const processLogin = (user) => {
    return {
            [RSAA]: {
                endpoint: "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/sign-in",
                method: "POST",
                body: JSON.stringify({email: user.email, password: user.password}),
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
                types: ['LOGIN', 'LOGIN_SUCCESS', 'LOGIN_FAILURE']
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks... I tried both ways but the problem isn't gone... I don't know why perhaps I should give up using api pattern

Comment: @Juntae Also enhancer should be the third argument.

Comment: Hi, Thanks, I got the reason and fixed it Thanks